# Python ORM for google-cloud-datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I've migrated a 1st Gen GAE Python 2 app to 2nd Gen GAE Python 3.  It was not easy but everything seems to be working.

I'd now like to migrate from google-cloud-ndb to google-cloud-datastore.  With google-cloud-datastore, is it ok to subclass `Entity` (which is a dict subclass) in a similar way to subclassing `ndb.Model`?

For example google-cloud-ndb code looks like this:

```
from google.cloud import ndb

class Foo(ndb.Model):
    x = ndb.StringProperty(default='42')

    def do_something(self):
        pass
```

Is this the right way to migrate the above to google-cloud-datastore?:

```
from google.cloud.datastore.entity import Entity

class Foo(Entity):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self['x'] = '42'

    def do_something(self):
        pass
```

I haven't seen any example code like this so I'd like to confirm that this is a good practice, especially with overriding `__init__`.

Even better, is there a way to subclass Entity so that I could access the data as object attributes (`foo.x`) instead of as a dictionary (`foo['x']`)?  That would make migration much easier.

Comment: Hi there, have you had any chance to go through the following codelab? Step 5 bullet 3 shares some good info about how the migration from Cloud ndb to datastore should be. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-gae-python-migrate-3-datastore#4

Comment: @AntonioRamirez, yes, I read that before asking my question.

Comment: Projects working on this but no established solution: [datastore-entity](https://github.com/komlasapaty/datastore-entity) and [datastore-orm](https://github.com/cirbuk/datastore-orm)

Comment: I suspect that google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity is not meant to be extended. The last view years the API stability of the  google-cloud-* offerings was very fluid, so I would suggest caution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the solution in my question is not a good one and that something like this would be better:

```
from google.cloud.datastore.entity import Entity

class Foo():

    x: str

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = '42'

    def do_something(self):
        pass

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'x': self.x}

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(self, data):
        f = Foo()
        f.x = data['x']
        return f
```

Would be great to get feedback from someone who has gone through this already.